# In a scrollable flex container children should get full height

Tags: css, flexbox

Here is the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4dmf91qa/)

In a scrollable flex container, I want all the children should get full height. In the following example you can see `div 2` can have large text body and it is causing the scroll behaviour.
When I set the height to both of them only `div 2` take the height but not `div 1`

How can we fix this behaviour using CSS? Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n3zpd1hy/)

Here is the screenshot
[image]

Here is the markup

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item1">
    div 1
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
    div 2 
    large text causing scroll behaviour
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-height: 200px;
  background: gray;
  overflow-y: auto;
}


.item1 {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.item2 {
  height: 100%;  
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want that `div1` is the same size as `div2` or the container?

Comment: same size as `div2` should work but as you can see `div2` is taking height same as the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `max-height` and `overflow` should be applied to a wrapper and not to `flex-container`. The items will be automatically the same size so you can drop the `height: 100%`.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: gray;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="item">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      2
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor turpis id turpis ultrices, nec tincidunt ligula cursus.
      <!-- Repeat the text to ensure overflow -->
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor turpis id turpis ultrices, nec tincidunt ligula cursus.
      <!-- Repeat the text to ensure overflow -->
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor turpis id turpis ultrices, nec tincidunt ligula cursus.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor turpis id turpis ultrices, nec tincidunt ligula cursus.
      <!-- Repeat the text to ensure overflow -->
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor turpis id turpis ultrices, nec tincidunt ligula cursus.
      <!-- Repeat the text to ensure overflow -->
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor turpis id turpis ultrices, nec tincidunt ligula cursus.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor turpis id turpis ultrices, nec tincidunt ligula cursus.
      <!-- Repeat the text to ensure overflow -->
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor turpis id turpis ultrices, nec tincidunt ligula cursus.
      <!-- Repeat the text to ensure overflow -->
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor turpis id turpis ultrices, nec tincidunt ligula cursus.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor turpis id turpis ultrices, nec tincidunt ligula cursus.
      <!-- Repeat the text to ensure overflow -->
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor turpis id turpis ultrices, nec tincidunt ligula cursus.
      <!-- Repeat the text to ensure overflow -->
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor turpis id turpis ultrices, nec tincidunt ligula cursus.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor turpis id turpis ultrices, nec tincidunt ligula cursus.
      <!-- Repeat the text to ensure overflow -->
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor turpis id turpis ultrices, nec tincidunt ligula cursus.
      <!-- Repeat the text to ensure overflow -->
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor turpis id turpis ultrices, nec tincidunt ligula cursus.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor turpis id turpis ultrices, nec tincidunt ligula cursus.
      <!-- Repeat the text to ensure overflow -->
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor turpis id turpis ultrices, nec tincidunt ligula cursus.
      <!-- Repeat the text to ensure overflow -->
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor turpis id turpis ultrices, nec tincidunt ligula cursus.

    </div>
    <!-- Add more child divs as needed -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Clever solution, it works Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For a scrollable flex container, you might need to set `.item1`'s position to `sticky` and `top` to 0, thus:

```css
.item1 {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

If that's not what you want to do, then I'd suggest making the tallest child scrollable, instead of the flex container, thus:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: gray;
}

.item1 {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.item2 {
  height: 100%;  
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

PS: You might want to take a look at the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#browser_compatibility) for `position: sticky`. It's supported in most modern browsers.

Comment: Thanks @Tobey for answering, Unfortunately I didn't want sticky.